# unix: for loop using strings

Tags: string, bash, unix, for-loop

I have the following for loop(s):

```
for p in 3UTR 5UTR coding_genic genic non_synonymous reg synonymous
do
    for i in 1 2 3 
    do
        qsub compute.job -v VAR1="$i", VAR2="$p"
    done    
done
```

So there is a for loop embedded in another for loop. The goal is to run the "qsub" command (submit jobs to a cluster computer), where the "VAR1" variables in "compute.job" are replaced by either 1, 2, or 3, and the "VAR2" variables replaced with one of the strings represented by p.

This part works just fine:

```
        for i in 1 2 3 
        do
            qsub compute.job -v VAR1="$i", VAR2="$p"
        done
```

But adding the other for loop doesn't... Any ideas on what might be wrong here? (I'm suspecting it has something to do with the strings...)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there should not be a space after the comma:

```
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="$i",VAR2="$p"
```

The actual p and i variables are set perfectly, I checked with an echo.

Comment: Thanks! the "compute.job" actually had a much longer name: "selection.Fst.indels.indel_GQ2500_PC.template.job". After changing it to actually be called "compute.job" it suddenly works. Not sure why that would matter...?

Answer (score 1):

what doesn't work?

```
$ cat ff 
for p in 3UTR 5UTR coding_genic genic non_synonymous reg synonymous
do
    for i in 1 2 3 
    do
        echo "qsub compute.job -v VAR1=\"$i\", VAR2=\"$p\""
    done    
done
$ ./ff 
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="1", VAR2="3UTR"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="2", VAR2="3UTR"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="3", VAR2="3UTR"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="1", VAR2="5UTR"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="2", VAR2="5UTR"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="3", VAR2="5UTR"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="1", VAR2="coding_genic"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="2", VAR2="coding_genic"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="3", VAR2="coding_genic"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="1", VAR2="genic"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="2", VAR2="genic"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="3", VAR2="genic"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="1", VAR2="non_synonymous"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="2", VAR2="non_synonymous"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="3", VAR2="non_synonymous"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="1", VAR2="reg"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="2", VAR2="reg"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="3", VAR2="reg"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="1", VAR2="synonymous"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="2", VAR2="synonymous"
qsub compute.job -v VAR1="3", VAR2="synonymous"
```